Load video on mobile device without autoplay
i have a video as background on my website.
<video loop="" playsinline="" muted="" preload="auto" oncontextmenu="return false;">
            <source src="..." type="video/mp4">
            Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>

On Desktop and Tablet everything works fine but when i look on Mobile the video was not loaded. Only when i add "autoplay" tag to the video the video load. But i do not want to autostart the video!

How can i load the video without autostart/autoplay and the user see the video in the background?

on mobile it's going to optimise use of network resources and not load a video until the user asks for it. If you want something visual to appear until user presses play, then maybe add a poster="...." attribute to the video
